# Joining historical tables with various suffixes in a VIEW

Tags: sql-server, view, sql-server-2000, union-all

In one of my larger tables, old records are moved to separate tables suffixed with the quarter and year.  For example, SILO_q1_2014

For historical queries, I usually use a view that encompasses the current table and all historical ones.  This would include the previous quarter, e.g. q2_2014, but would be out-of-date once we roll into 2014Q4 and the new q3_2014 table is created.

**So what is the best way to keep this view up to date with the latest quarters' tables?**

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[v_SILO]
AS
    SELECT     *
    FROM         dbo.SILO
    WHERE     active_flag = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT     *
    FROM         dbo.SILO_q2_2014
    WHERE     active_flag = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT     *
    FROM         dbo.SILO_q1_2014
    WHERE     active_flag = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT     *
    FROM         dbo.SILO_q4_2012
    WHERE     active_flag = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT     *
    FROM         dbo.SILO_q3_2012
    WHERE     active_flag = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT     *
    FROM         dbo.SILO_q2_2012
    WHERE     active_flag = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT     *
    FROM         dbo.SILO_q1_2012
    WHERE     active_flag = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT     *
    FROM         dbo.SILO_q4_2011
    WHERE     active_flag = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT     *
    FROM         dbo.SILO_q3_2011
    WHERE     active_flag = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT     *
    FROM         dbo.SILO_q2_2011
    WHERE     active_flag = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT     *
    FROM         dbo.SILO_q1_2011
    WHERE     active_flag = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT     *
    FROM         dbo.SILO_q4_2010
    WHERE     active_flag = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT     *
    FROM         dbo.SILO_q3_2010
    WHERE     active_flag = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT     *
    FROM         dbo.SILO_q2_2010
    WHERE     active_flag = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT     *
    FROM         dbo.SILO_q1_2010
    WHERE     active_flag = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT     *
    FROM         dbo.SILO_q4_2009
    WHERE     active_flag = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT     *
    FROM         dbo.SILO_q3_2009
    WHERE     active_flag = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT     *
    FROM         dbo.SILO_q2_2009
    WHERE     active_flag = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT     *
    FROM         dbo.SILO_q1_2009
    WHERE     active_flag = 1

GO
```

Note: This is in a **SQL 2000** db

Comment: What *up-to-date* means here?  Are you finding it difficult to re-create the view each quarter?

Comment: Edited.  Up-to-date meaning to include the latest quarter (next one would be q3_2014).  It's difficult when there are multiple views like these referencing multiple quarters.

Comment: Does it have to be a view?   If you could use a stored procedure that returns the same data, then you could use dynamic sql to make it self-updating.

Comment: I use this view in other queries and stored procedures (treating it much like a table) so I don't believe a stored proc could easily take its place.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a standard naming convention you could create a stored proc that would drop and re-create the view to include the current quarter.  Then, put that stored proc as a scheduled job in SQL Server that runs once a month.